# Mask number in form input to display only two decimals but save original value

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, input

I'm trying to format a number in a form input to display only two decimals BUT still keep (save) the original value. I need to do this because if I simply round the number and save it there will be incorrect values down the line. Plus the customer only wants to see two decimals at most.

I tried using this: https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ and this: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask but both these plugins will ignore the original value and just format it to "*.00". Ex: 134.277 will become 1342.77, which is very wrong.

I also tried this but unfortunately it just doesn't work: http://csspre.com/rounding-numbers/

Is it possible to round a number for **display** only?

Comment: Well you’d probably have to “split” this then, one hidden field to hold and submit the original value, and a fake one just for displaying purposes, into which you write your “formatted” value. But I can not see that making much sense to begin with, if that field is supposed to be for actual user input (and since you asked about _masking_, I am going to assume it is) - how would I change the value from 134.277 to 134.278, if I am not even shown that third decimal …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `toFixed` to do your rounding

```js
function doCustomRounding(obj){
    $("#"+obj.id).data("value", obj.value)
    $("#"+obj.id).val(Number(obj.value).toFixed(2));
}

function getOriginalValue(id){
    alert("original Value: "+$("#"+id).data("value"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="formattedNo" value = "0" type="number" onchange="doCustomRounding(this)" data-value="0" /><button onclick="getOriginalValue('formattedNo')">Get Original Value</button>
```

See above working snippet. Enter a number with decimal places then remove focus from the textbox.

**EDIT**

I used the data attribute to store the original value to avoid having to store in variables for each new input element

Comment: Thanks, but this is on a form with more than 30 input fields. It would be painful to store every original value like this :P

Comment: Your edit is almost exactly what I ended up doing :)
By the way, I'm using the "alt" attribute to store the original value. That way I don't have to place a "data-value" by hand at every input, right?

Comment: sounds pretty much the same. You'll still have to set the `alt` attribute somehow @PedroAraujoJorge

Answer (score 0):

You can use the toFixed() method when you are printing the value.

Documentation on toFixed(): https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: But then when I submit the form the rounded value will be sent, right? What I want is to keep the original input value.